# Passing properties files to JBoss in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, configuration, jboss, properties-file

As I have been trying to make the switch from Eclipse to IntelliJ possible at work, I am nearly there. The last issue I am running into is the configuration of a local JBoss in IntelliJ.

In Eclipse we pass three properties files to our JBoss server, by adding some parameters into the *Program Arguments* (double-click the JBoss server in Servers list -> In General Information click *Open launch configuration*). Specifically: `-P="../standalone/configuration/my.properties"`

How can I deploy these three files into the local JBoss server in IntelliJ? I have tried passing them as environment variables, to no success.

Comment: I think you have to go to Startup/Connection tab, uncheck Use Default for the start up scripts, click the second `...` button, and enter program arguments.  See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/run-debug-configuration-jboss-server.html